# css div height issue

Tags: css

I've got this issue with a site design.

1. When resizing the site (in height) the text of div #output go's over the footer, over the edge. I want to keep it inside the white part of #output's container div.
2. In ie7, #output doesn't stretch 100%, can't seem to fix that.

I've made a copy of this site, you can check it out at following url: http://test21.c-tz.nl/index.php?id=main

Comment: Just above where #footer begins, try adding `<div style="clear:both;"></div>`.

Comment: And don't forget to upvote a good answer too. :)

Comment: Ah ok, thnx hehe ^_^ and thnx for the late welcome. I just arived from the middle ages where it was etiquette to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is being caused by the margin on top of #output, the DIV that is getting that fancy scrollbar stuff applied to it. The JavaScript is setting the height correctly, but when you add the margin, the container is too large.

You could try adding another DIV inside of the #output DIV and calling the JavaScript on that instead. That would allow you to keep the margin you have and hopefully allow the JavaScript to calculate the width appropriately.

Comment: Sir, you are a genius. This is just what I needed. Why didn't I think of this myself. All goes well from this point =] Thankyou.